# Building webhost in takes long time in dockerized Spa Application

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core

I have several applications running in my docker-compose. Most of them are simple API applications, but I also have one SPA (Angular) web app. For some reason this app takes a really long time to run. I looked a bit closer and found out that it is the WebHostBuilder.Build() that is taking a long time. I added the code below to every Program.cs file so I could compare times with other projects.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Gateway building");
    var sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    var build = CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build();
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Gateway running: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    build.Run();
}
```

Here is the output I got after starting my docker compose

> Identity api building
>   Blog api building
>   Web app building
>   Gateway building
>   Identity api running: 19245
>   Blog api running: 28822
>   Gateway running: 25977
>   Web app running: 105640

As you see, the web app is 4-5 times slower than all the others. The startup from my web app is still fairly straightforward. I don't do much besides initializing the SpaStaticFiles:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration => configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist");
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

    app.UseSpa(spa => spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp");
}
```

My dockerfile is also pretty similar to other dockerfiles:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src

FROM node:10.15 as node-build
WORKDIR /web
COPY /ClientApp .
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build:prod

FROM build as publish
WORKDIR /src
COPY . .
COPY --from=node-build /ClientApp/dist ./ClientApp/dist
RUN dotnet publish arnvanhoutte.Client.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "arnvanhoutte.Client.dll"]
```

Above here is the dockerfile of my webapp, below is the dockerfile of an api

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /identity
EXPOSE 80

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY arnvanhoutte.Identity/arnvanhoutte.Identity.csproj arnvanhoutte.Identity/
RUN dotnet restore arnvanhoutte.Identity/arnvanhoutte.Identity.csproj
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/arnvanhoutte.Identity
RUN dotnet build arnvanhoutte.Identity.csproj -c Release -o /identity

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish arnvanhoutte.Identity.csproj -c Release -o /identity

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /identity
COPY --from=publish /identity .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "arnvanhoutte.Identity.dll"]
```

Both the docker-compose and the override file are pretty basic I believe

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  gateway:
    image: ${REGISTRY:-arnvanhoutte}gateway:${PLATFORM:-linux}-${TAG:-latest}
    build:
      context: ./arnvanhoutte.Gateway
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - web
      - blog
      - identity
  web:
    image: ${REGISTRY:-arnvanhoutte}web:${PLATFORM:-linux}-${TAG:-latest}
    build:
      context: ./arnvanhoutte.Client
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - blog
      - identity
  blog:
    image: ${REGISTRY:-arnvanhoutte}blog:${PLATFORM:-linux}-${TAG:-latest}
    build:
      context: ./arnvanhoutte.Blog
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - identity
  identity:
    image: ${REGISTRY:-arnvanhoutte}identity:${PLATFORM:-linux}-${TAG:-latest}
    build:
      context: ./arnvanhoutte.Identity
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

Docker override:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  gateway:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
      - ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=44385
    ports:
      - "7100:80"
      - "44385:443"
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro
      - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
  web:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
    ports:
      - "7101:80"
  blog:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
    ports:
      - "7102:80"
  identity:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
    ports:
      - "7103:80"
```

I genuinely don't understand why it is taking so long. If I run it in normal mode instead of in docker it does build pretty quickly (just over 1 sec), so I think something must be wrong with my docker container

Comment: If you comment out `app.UseSpa(spa => spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp");`,  will it run quickly? Does this issue exist with built-in Asp.Net Core angular template?

Comment: I get exactly the same results. This is with the built-in template